# Where's the best place to report bugs with the GMail app?

Tags: gmail

I want to report a bug / RFE with the official GMail app, but I'm finding it hard to find the right place to do this - all the forums / discussion groups I've found so far seem to be moribund (eg not much activity since 2008).

What's the recommended place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [this comment](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12373#c3), the place for bug reports seems to be via the About -> Send Feedback link within the GMail app - this links to this survey page:

http://www.google.com/m/survey/mail_ca

Answer (score 2):

The official issue database for bugs/features/etc. of the Android OS can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

Comment: Hmm, I found someone had already reported the issue I'd found, but someone said that's the wrong place: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12373

Comment: As per the comment in the thread the GMail App isn't part of the Android OS project.