# Is there an Android known issues database?

Tags: security, bugs

Does anyone know if there is a Known Issues Database for Android, 
or some tool that one could search for known issues based on the version of some parts of the code such as the kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official issue database for bugs/features/etc. of the Android OS can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

<sub>Copied from [Bryan Denny's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/wheres-the-best-place-to-report-bugs-with-the-gmail-app/2666#2666) to another question.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this link will help me. Any idea on how to find out the known issues for the components in android?
Such as the kernel or the dalvik vm.

Comment: @Luander I would have assumed they were in the same spot.  Kernels are often heavily modified by the manufacturer, though, so if you encounter an issue it might not be Google's fault.

Comment: One more question: Do you know if there's a way to list all libs and components in some android compiled build? Because if I knew the version of each libs and/or component I would be able to serach for known issues specific for that libs or component

Comment: @Luander Sorry, no idea.